# How can i update a table using SQL Injection?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

How can i able to update a table in a **MySQL database using SQL Injection**?

I have heard about how we can enter the query in the address bar and it is possible to update a table in the MySQL database. But I am not sure about it.

Kindly give me an idea professionals...

Comment: This looks like a nice tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to try entering `Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --` in your form :)

[image]

In the above [xkcd cartoon](http://xkcd.com/327/), Bobby was probably asked to fill in his name in a form, but he mischievously inserted `Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --` as his name. Now imagine if that input was used in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = '$input'
```

As you can see, if we substitute `$input` for what Bobby entered, you'll get this

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --'
```

Which are two very valid SQL commands, and a comment.

You may also want to research earlier [Stack Overflow questions on SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection).

Comment: Is it possible to change by updating the table by entering the query in URL. kindly explain

Comment: @Fero: Yes it is. For example, if you use the querystring from the URL, and insert it into a `SELECT` statement, as in `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$querystring';` Then whatever you pass as the querystring can easily terminate that `SELECT` statement, and execute any another statement, as in the above cartoon.

Comment: In the above cartoon, Bobby was probably asked to fill in his name in a form, but he mischievously inserted  `Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --`... Now imagine if that input was used in this query: `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = '$input'`... As you can see, if you substitute `$input` for what Bobby entered, you'll get this: `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --'`, which are two valid SQL commands.

Comment: @Fero: You may want to start with the link that @Piskvor suggested in the above comments. Then I'd recommend going through Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Robert'); DROP TABLE students; -- Might have worked in 2010. But as of today 2021. mysql_query() do not allow stacked queries.