# MSSQL Query Error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column <X>."

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

[image]

Following error occurs in /// this coding "

***Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'boarding', table 'C:\USERS\VBI SERVER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\WEBSITES\VOLVO\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF.dbo.boardingpt'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.***

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO boardingpt (service, travelid, bdpt_name, time) VALUES('" & Trim(TextBox3.Text.ToString) & "', '" & Trim(TextBox4.Text.ToString) & "', '" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.ToString) & "','" & Trim(TextBox2.Text.ToString) & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you assign the value to 'boarding' ? it is required.

Comment: on a side note - i suggest you read up on sql injection attacks - as your code is *extremely* vulnerable to that. I tried to find the DROP Freddy Tables cartoon but couldn't find it. dang.

Comment: Ahh, Bobby Tables - no wonder i couldn't find it. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890091/how-can-i-update-a-table-using-sql-injection/3890107#3890107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Column to an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

or under SSMS in the column defintion select

`Table Designer -> Identity Specification -> (Is Identity)` to `true`

Comment: I would normally agree with you, however, it is not _clear_ from the question that the field _should_ be an identity field. Yes, it would resolve the problem, but is it the correct data model?

Comment: If you look at the Table design, that would almost be the obvious choice. Or maybe it shoudl be a foreign key then?

Comment: My point is that without knowing more about the field, we can't _categorically_ say it should be an Identity field. And yes, it _could_ very well be a foreign key. There isn't enough information, IMHO.

Comment: I thought that maybe the INSERT statement provided seemed like a good point to start from...

Comment: Agree with @astander - it's an INT, and it's a PK. Given also the table is called Boarding, pretty safe bet it should be an identity column. As you say though, can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing a value for the `boarding` field, which is a `NOT NULL` field (`Allow Nulls` is not checked).

Being a `NOT NULL` field means you *have* to provide a value for it.

If the field is supposed to be the ID of the rows in the table, you should make it into an `IDENTITY` field.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290124.aspx#dvmscchangingcolumnsidentityproperties) on MSDN for how to change the identity properties using the Visual Studio Database designer.

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the boarding column to be `Identity`, so is trying to put a null in there (as you haven't provided its value in the insert query)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert NULL value for the column which is set to NOT NULL.

Solution

- Make **boarding** column to ALLOW NULL and remove Primary key (because primary key never can be null)

or

- Set IDENTITY to YES in your table design mode for **boarding** column

Hope this helps

Thanks
Vivek